# Can the Authorize.Net CIM hosted form design be customized?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

When, submit form via getHostedProfilePageRequest, it will be redirect to https://test.authorize.net/profile/addpayment.
Can we change css or design for it?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't change the design of it. If you want more control of the design you will need to use the non-hosted CIM API. But since you can embed the form in an iframe or lightbox you can integrate it directly into your wesite anyway, so the customizations you would want to make to it should be minimal anyway.

Comment: Note, that using a CIM form that you host, process and then submit to Auth.net via API will may you to be PCI compliant.